# Any Data Structures & Algorithms books w/ examples in Objective-C or other Keyword Message Language?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, data-structures, message-passing

I've tried searching for Data Structure / Algorithms books that provide examples in either Objective-C, or another language supporting keyword message syntax, to no avail.

The reason I'm interested in this is because I really think the keyword syntax would help me understand the intent of code, which I find I have to think longer about in languages with typical function call syntax.

A good example is this snippet from a [SplayTree](http://www.koders.com/c/fid5FC24BB3722C2B1D68216878F2C4AA2006018F59.aspx) implementation in C:

```
/* Continue down the tree.  */
n = splay_tree_splay_helper (sp, key, next, node, parent);
```

The function name is pretty unhelpful, and even with the comment I have to thoroughly read the code to have any idea what's really happening there.

I know that technically any piece of C code is valid Objective-C, but I'm looking for something that structures algorithm implementations utilizing a good object model like Objective-C's since I believe the resulting code is more maintainable. This may seem counter-intuitive in the performance restricted space of algorithm design, but I've seen plenty of Algorithms books that have examples in idiomatic Ruby, Python, Javascript etc.

Basically I'm looking for anything with a good object model that allows for very descriptive keyword messages, whether it's Objective-C or even (though probably unlikely) anything else in the Smalltalk family.

Comment: What do you mean by "keyword syntax?"

Comment: In short, a.doSomething(b,c,d) in C becomes something like [a doSomethingWith: b on: c with: d] in Obj-C. See (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html). This would also be something like a doSomethingWith: b on: c with: d. in Smalltalk. Note in both cases method signature becomes 'doSomethingWith:on:with:' versus 'doSomething'. Not the best example but a huge help when naming a function with a lot of args and encoding what it means.

Comment: Ah: I think the general term for that is "named [function] arguments," not "keyword syntax." [Keywords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_(computer_programming)) are usually reserved words.

Comment: Not exactly. Since in most languages (that I know of) named args don't actually have any effect on the method signature. Depending on the language this can lead to some overloading issues.

Comment: FYI, the originator of the syntax you are asking about is [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), also known for being the one of the first object-oriented programming languages. You might enjoy reading about Smalltalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want a book? Just download a [smalltalk environment](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download) and read the whole actual source. Open a system browser, select one of the Collections categories (collection of classes) and start browsing the code (the extra column is for message categories). Open a workspace, type Object cmd-B (or ctrl-B, for browse) and see for yourself why the single responsibility principle was invented. Navigate through the code with hierarchy, senders and implementors.

Comment: Winner. No idea why I didn't jump to this. I'm going with Pharo, and while the documentation is a little bit sparse, the code is beautiful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the wrong thing.

A good algorithms and data structures books will try to not waste your time with hard to read source code. Most of the good books I know spend most of their time explaining things at a high level and only show actual code in small snippets that can be easily understood independently of the language used and how proficient you are with it.

It doesn't matter how convoluted some guy's implementation of splay trees is. As long as you know what the splay tree is you should be able to implement your own version without looking at hit too much.

And finally, a good object model and nice syntax is not the be-all-end-all of things. Many datastructures make use of union types that are not very nicely implemented in OO style and the naming patterns and syntax are things you should be able to get used to very quickly.

Comment: Again, I did not say that OO was be-all-end-all, only that it's a proven paradigm of code reuse / maintainability and it fits the way I understand things. I'm not claiming, for example, that a DataStructs/Alg book with examples in Haskell wouldn't be useful, but it's not what I'm looking for. Also, while some people may be fine with hand wavy pseudo-code, I personally am not, and prefer to look at something concrete that both explains itself and actually can be quickly looked up and implemented for real world use on demand.

Comment: Well, good luck then. But you will probably have a hard time since so much of the algorithms literature is hand-wavy pseudocode.